# I want to add my two list items in a dictionary

Tags: python, random, module

I am writing a code for a time table maker. This code takes the subjects that you want to study and the preference of studying(morning,afternoon,evening). Then I take total hours to be studied(20 hours) in a week. Then I divide it by 7 to calculate the study per day. Then I want to assign a random subject to my random time slot.

```
# Time Table Creator
import random
def TimeTableCreator(subjects,day,time_slots,total_hours):
    day = {}
    studyperday = total_hours/7
    studyperday = round(studyperday)

    subjects_study = random.sample(subjects,k=studyperday) # subjects that are selected randomly
    final_time_slots = random.sample(time_slots,k=studyperday) # list of my time slots
#trying to add both these items using for loop in a dictionary
    for subject in subjects_study:
        for i in range(studyperday):
         day[subject] = final_time_slots[i]

    print(day)
subjects = []
while True:
    subject = input("Enter a subject:\n")
    if subject=="":
        break
    subjects.append(subject)
    total_hours = 20


print("What is your preference of studying: Morning or afternoon or evening:")
time_preference = input()
if time_preference.lower()=="morning":
    time_slots = ["7:00-8:00","8:00-9:00","9:00-10:00","10:00-11:00","2:00-3:00"]
elif time_preference.lower()=="afternoon":
    time_slots = ["12:00-13:00","13:00-14:00","15:00-16:00","16:00-17:00","18:00-19:00"]
elif time_preference.lower()=="evening":
    time_slots = ["16:00-17:00","18:00-19:00","19:00-20:00","20:00-21:00","21:00-22:00"]
else:
    print("Invalid preference")
TimeTableCreator(subjects,"Monday",time_slots,total_hours)
```

Program output

```
Enter a subject:
phy
Enter a subject:
chem
Enter a subject:
bio
Enter a subject:

What is your preference of studying: Morning or afternoon or evening:
morning
**{'chem': '2:00-3:00', 'phy': '2:00-3:00', 'bio': '2:00-3:00'}**

Process finished with exit code 0
```

**As you can see the time slot is the same that is assigned to different subjects. But I want that time slots should be different for each subject.I want that the time slots should be different for each subject. It is showing 2:00 to 3:00 for each subject. But I want different slots to be assigned for different subjects**
Please help.

Comment: what is your expected output

Comment: I want that the time slots should be different for each subject. It is showing 2:00 to 3:00 for each subject. But I want different slots to be assigned for different subjects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is dictionary creation. You don't need the nested loop. You can use [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#zip)

Just change this to

```
for subject in subjects_study:
        for i in range(studyperday):
         day[subject] = final_time_slots[i]
```

this

```
for x, y in zip(subjects_study, final_time_slots):
    day[x] = y
```

One liner solution:

```
day = dict(zip(subjects_study, final_time_slots))
```

Comment: @Vasu https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip

Answer (score 1):

```
# Time Table Creator
import random
def TimeTableCreator(subjects,day,time_slots,total_hours):
    day = {}
    studyperday = round(total_hours/7)

    subjects_study = random.sample(subjects,k=studyperday) # subjects that are selected randomly
    final_time_slots = random.sample(time_slots,k=studyperday) # list of my time slots
#trying to add both these items using for loop in a dictionary
    i = 0
    for subject in subjects_study:
         day[subject] = final_time_slots[i]
         i += 1

    print(day)
```

You were using a nested for loop, that assigned each value of subject from each final_total_hours and therefore it ended up at the same random value (the last one).
This only needed a single for loop as above.

Comment: Anyways, you have a very well formatted code. Was easily understandable :)

Comment: Thanks. I was making a time table creator and now I have successfully made it. 

Here is the usecase of it:
This program generates a time table according to your time preference (morning,afternoon,evening). Subjects are randomly selected but the time slots are fixed so that you get a habit of studying at that particular time.

Now I have run my same function and created the time table for all 7 days.

Comment: Yes, I was able to follow the code, nicely commented!

Answer (score 0):

You are looping using nested loops so are going through all the `i` values for each subject and ending up with the value for the last value of `i` for all the subjects:

```
    for subject in subjects_study:
        for i in range(studyperday):
         day[subject] = final_time_slots[i]
```

what you are wanting is to loop together using `enumerate`:

```
    for i, subject in enumerate(subjects_study):
        day[subject] = final_time_slots[i]
```

Comment: @Vasu You're welcome. I think in fact that deadshot's answer with zip is probably neater. I tried to stay closer to your original code, and I'll leave it up because I think it is instructive for you to see how `enumerate` works, but for pairs of corresponding items from two lists, I think on reflection that you should use `zip`.